# Question about 3-regular graphs with a restriction (also fullerene and four color theorem)

Tags: graph-theory

(Crossposted to mathoverflow.net)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120162/question-about-3-regular-graphs-with-a-restriction-also-fullerene-and-four-color

Studying all 3-regular graphs that have only faces with 5 edges or more (simplified), I empirically found (computer program) that many hypothetically possible graphs, that by Euler's identity may exist ($F5 = 12 + F7 + 2F8 + 3F9 + ...$), do not actually exist. Using a VF2 algorithm to filter out isomorphic maps being created, I also noticed that not so many graphs as I expected exist. And that one general category of graphs, that always represents a simplified 3-regular graph, is that of fullerenes (with 12 faces F5 and an arbitrary number of F6). Here is a list of what I found, so far, for each class of graphs, from 12 faces to 20 faces (surrounding area included).

**The question is**: Since the computation of maps with 17, 18, 19, 20 faces (simplified and not containing isomorphic graphs) it is taking very long time (days of CPU time on a PC), is this sequence already known?

- 12 faces: 1 (only 1 graph exists)

  - On 3 dimentional space (sphere) it is a dodecahedron
  - It is a fullerene: 20-fullerene Dodecahedral graph
- 13 faces: 0 (no simplified graphs exist with 13 faces)

  - The hypothetical (by Euler's identity) map of 12 F5 and 1 F6 **does not exist**
- 14 faces: 1 (12 F5 + 2 F6)

  - he hypothetical (by Euler's identity) map of 13 F5 and 1 F7 **does not exist**
  - It is a fullerene: GP (12,2) Generalized Petersen graph
- 15 faces: 1 (12 F5 + 3 F6)

  - The hypothetical (by Euler's identity) map of 14 F5 and 1 F8 **does not exist**
  - It is a fullerene: 26-Fullerene
- 16 faces: 3 (Two graphs are 12 F5 + 4 F6. The other has 14 F5 + 2 F7)

  - The hypothetical (by Euler's identity) map of 14 F5 and 2 F7 **does exists**
  - The other two are Fullerenes
- 17 faces: ???
- 18 faces: ???
- 19 faces: ???
- 20 faces: ???

ADD (28/Jan/2013):

- Images of these graphs are here: http://4coloring.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/four-color-theorem-simplified-maps-and-fullerenes/

Comment: Have you checked [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=fullerene+&sort=&language=&go=Search)? BTW +1 cool question. add the chemistry-tag...;-) I would expect 17 and 19 to have no graphs...

Comment: I did a quick check but for now the sequence 1,0,1,1,3 has 252 match. I suppose still too few elements!

Comment: ... [OEIS 1,0,1,1,3,0,_,0](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C0%2C_%2C0&sort=&language=&go=Search)...

Comment: With 17 and 19 faces for sure fullerene exist: http://hog.grinvin.org/Fullerenes

Comment: cool, I just thought about assuming Barnette conjecture and using grinberg's theorem to exclude some cases, but (i) it seems obsolete now and (ii) I gotta go. Good nite...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered on MO.